# print from user to screen with (enter)

Tags: printing, output

i'am tray to print a strings from user to screen the problem i faced that i nedd when user insert (enter)key the program go to new line and user still have the ability to print on screen , but when i insert (enter)the program go to the first line and overwrite the old words here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
int len;
char searsh_word[10];
char ch;
    printf("enter your strings\n");
while(ch!='EOF'){
    ch=getch();
    printf("%c",ch);
   }
puts("\nEnter the word you need to search for : ");
scanf("%s",searsh_word);
len=strlen(searsh_word);
printf("your word length is : %d",len);


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was by useing getch() you can use grtchar() for better result

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
FILE *file;
int main()
{
int len;
char searsh_word[10];
char ch;
file=fopen("test.txt","w");
if(!file){
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        exit(1);
}else{
    printf("enter your strings\n");
    }
    do{
    ch=getchar();
    fprintf(file,"%c",ch);
   }while(ch!='.');
   fclose(file);
puts("\nEnter the word you need to search for : ");
scanf("%s",searsh_word);
len=strlen(searsh_word);
printf("your word length is : %d",len);


return 0;
}
```